# Inserting element in a linked list (Project InsertElement raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV' )

Tags: pointers, linked-list, pascal

I wrote this program, which is supposed to create a linked list of integers from user input until the user inserts '0', print it, add an element at the end of it and then print the linked list again, including the added element.

When I run it, the input and the first output work fine, but when it comes to adding the new element I get the following error message:

> "Project InsertElement raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV' in
>   file 'InsertElement.lpr' at line 66: OutRefEnd^.next := RefNew;"

Clearly, there is a problem with line 66:

```
OutRefEnd^.next := RefNew;
```

but I can't figure out what that problem is, if it has to do with my code at all, or if it's just the compiler. From what I understand, the error code implies that 'outRefEnd^.next'` points to an empty address, but since I am assigning it the value 'RefNew', I don't quite understand why this should be an issue in the first place.

Could somebody please give me a hint as to where I went wrong?

Here's my code:

```pascal
program InserElement(input, output);
    {Has the user type in integers and forms a linked list out of them,
    then inserts an element at the end of that linked list and prints the
    linked list with the added new element}

    {$mode objfpc}{$H+}

    uses
      {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
      cthreads,
      {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
      Classes;

    type
      tRefList = ^tList;
      tList = record
                 info : integer;
                 next : tRefList
                end;
    var
     RefBeginning: tRefList;
     RefEnd : tRefList;
     Pointer : tRefList;
     Number : integer;



       procedure CreateList( var outRefBeginning: tRefList);
       { Creates a linear list through user input }


      begin
       readln(Number);
       while Number <> 0 do
       begin
         new (Pointer);
         Pointer^.info := Number;
         Pointer^.next := outRefBeginning;
         outRefBeginning := Pointer;
         readln (Number)
       end { while-loop }
      end; {CreateList}

    procedure InsertElement(inNumber : integer; var outRefBeginning : tRefList; var outRefEnd : tRefList);
      { Inserts a new element at the end of the list. outRefBeginning points to the first
      element of that list, outRefEnd points to the last element of it. The Value of inNumber is
      assigned to the record component info of the new element}

      var
       RefNew : tRefList;

      begin
      { Create and initialise new element }
      new(RefNew);
      RefNew^.info := inNumber;
      RefNew^.next := nil;
      { Insert element at the end of the linear list }
      if outRefBeginning = nil then
         begin
         outRefBeginning := RefNew;
         outRefEnd := RefNew
         end
         else
             begin
               outRefEnd^.next := RefNew;
               outRefEnd := RefNew;
             end;
      end;{ InsertElement }

      procedure PrintList;
      { Prints all elements of the linked list }

      var
       RefNew : tRefList;

      begin
       RefNew := RefBeginning;
       while RefNew <>  nil do
       begin
         writeln (RefNew^.info);
         RefNew := RefNew^.next
       end;
      end;

    begin
      RefBeginning := nil;
      RefEnd := RefBeginning;
      CreateList(RefBeginning);
      PrintList;
      InsertElement(5,RefBeginning,RefEnd);
      PrintList;
      readln;
    end.
```

**[edit]**
For anyone who is interested, I'll paste the corrected code below, which I changed according to the suggestions in Tom's answer.

Changes:

1. I deleted the pointer variable, as it is no longer needed:

   ```
   var
    RefBeginning: tRefList;
    RefEnd : tRefList;
    Number : integer;
   ```
2. I changed the `procedure CreateList` to resemble the `procedure InsertElement` in that it saves the vaue of the new element not only in `RefBeginning`, but also in `RefEnd`:

   ```
    procedure CreateList(var outRefBeginning: tRefList; var OutRefEnd:  tRefList);
          { Creates a linear list through user input }
         var
          RefNew : tRefList;`

     begin
      writeln('Please key in natural numbers. Key in 0 once you are done. ');
      readln(Number);
      while Number <> 0 do
      begin
        new (RefNew);
        RefNew^.info := Number;
        RefNew^.next := nil;
        if outRefBeginning = nil then
         begin
         outRefBeginning := RefNew;
         OutRefEnd := RefNew;
         end
        else
        begin
          outRefEnd^.next := RefNew;
          outRefEnd := RefNew
        end;
        readln (Number)
      end; { while-loop }
     end; {CreateList}
   ```

   And last but not least, here's the complete code:

   ```
   program InserElement(input, output);
       {Has the user type in integers and forms a linked list out of them,
       then inserts an element at the end of that linked list and prints the
       linked list with the added new element}

   {$mode objfpc}{$H+}

   uses
     {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
     cthreads,
     {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
     Classes;

   type
     tRefList = ^tList;
     tList = record
                info : integer;
                next : tRefList
               end;
   var
    RefBeginning: tRefList;
    RefEnd : tRefList;
    Number : integer;



      procedure CreateList(var outRefBeginning: tRefList; var OutRefEnd: tRefList);
      { Creates a linear list through user input }
     var
      RefNew : tRefList;

     begin
      writeln('Please key in natural numbers. Key in 0 once you are done. ');
      readln(Number);
      while Number <> 0 do
      begin
        new (RefNew);
        RefNew^.info := Number;
        RefNew^.next := nil;
        if outRefBeginning = nil then
         begin
         outRefBeginning := RefNew;
         OutRefEnd := RefNew;
         end
        else
        begin
          outRefEnd^.next := RefNew;
          outRefEnd := RefNew
        end;
        readln (Number)
      end; { while-loop }
     end; {CreateList}

   procedure InsertElement(inNumber : integer; var outRefBeginning : tRefList; var outRefEnd : tRefList);
     { Inserts a new element at the end of the list. outRefBeginning points to the first
     element of that list, outRefEnd points to the last element of it. The Value of inNumber is
     assigned to the record component info of the new element}

     var
      RefNew : tRefList;

     begin
     { Create and initialise new element }
     new(RefNew);
     RefNew^.info := inNumber;
     RefNew^.next := nil;
     { Insert element at the end of the linear list }
     if outRefBeginning = nil then
        begin
        outRefBeginning := RefNew;
        outRefEnd := RefNew
        end
        else
            begin
              outRefEnd^.next := RefNew;
              outRefEnd := RefNew;
            end;
     end;{ InsertElement }

     procedure PrintList;
     { Prints all elements of the linked list }

     var
      RefNew : tRefList;

     begin
      RefNew := RefBeginning;
      while RefNew <>  nil do
      begin
        writeln (RefNew^.info);
        RefNew := RefNew^.next
      end;
     end;

   begin
     RefBeginning := nil;
     RefEnd := nil;
     CreateList(RefBeginning, RefEnd);
     InsertElement(5,RefBeginning,RefEnd);
     PrintList;
     readln;
   end.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You went wrong in `procedure CreateList();` in that you add new records to the beginning and not to the end. `RefEnd` is still `nil` after `CreateList()`.

When you then call `InsertElement(5,RefBeginning,RefEnd);` with `RefEnd = nil` the error is triggered on the line `outRefEnd^.next := RefNew;` as the parameter `outRefEnd` is nil.

You should correct the `CreateList()` procedure to basically work similar as `InsertElement` with respect to linking initial item to both `outRefBeginning` and `outRefEnd` and subsequent new items to `outRefEnd`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I posted my corrected code above for anyone who is interested.